# Resuming does not come in my app at windows phone 7

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-7.1, indexoutofboundsexception

now i have done a puzzle app in windows phone 7 and this has been failed in windows store app because of which is not resuming when user press first start key and after back pressing key, actually problem is, i have 9 images that is stored in array and assign each images into another image controls when load the page, but it will be working as a first time running and problem occurred when pressing start after pressing back key as i told earlier, but i got the exception of image does not assign from array variable at such a situation, please tell me is there any solution to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the problem. Can you post your code where you're assigning the image, and the full text of the exception?

Comment: My code is 
                Image img = new Image();
                img.Source = bi;

               Image maskImage = new Image();

                if (levelId == 1)
                {
                     maskImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(easy_Mask[count1++], UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); 
                   
                }

Comment: from this code, image variable does not assign the source to the maskImage when running at pressing start key and after pressing back key in the phone but which will be working well at first time load the page, so pls tell me how to solve this problem?.